# How to set index of QTreeView as first item in tree automatically

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have a program that when clicking an item in a QTreeView shows details about the item and at the click of a button you can open the file, however if no file is selected the program closes. I have tried `setCurrentIndex()` however I'm not sure if I'm using it right at the only exampled i can find are PyQt4 or C++.

I'm runnng PyQt5 windows 7.

```
    self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralWidget)
    self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.treeView)
    self.file_model=QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
    self.file_model.setRootPath('C:\My Stuff\Movies')
    self.treeView.setModel(self.file_model)
    self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.file_model.index('C:\My Stuff\Movies'))
    self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
    self.treeView.hideColumn(1)
    self.treeView.hideColumn(2)
    self.treeView.hideColumn(3)
    self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(self.file_model.index(0,0))
```

Alternatively, i would prefer if a `QMessagebox` to appear say no file is selected, i have made the message box and it is working however i cant get it to show when no file is selected in the tree view as the program crashes before it displays the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.file_model.index(0,0)` just gives you the information of the root directory, in your case, `C:`. What you need to do, is wait for the `directoryLoaded( QString )` signal to be emitted, then choose the index at `(0, 0)`

Here is the simplified version of the code. Perhaps you can make the necessary changes in your code.

```
import os, sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    app = QApplication( sys.argv )

    treeView = QTreeView()
    treeView.setSortingEnabled( True )
    treeView.setObjectName("treeView")

    fsm = QFileSystemModel()
    fsm.setRootPath( 'C:\My Stuff\Movies' )

    def selectZeroZero( path ) :
        if fsm.rowCount( fsm.index( path ) ) :
            treeView.setCurrentIndex( fsm.index( 0, 0, fsm.index( path ) ) )

    fsm.directoryLoaded.connect( selectZeroZero )

    treeView.setModel( fsm )
    treeView.setRootIndex( fsm.index( 'C:\My Stuff\Movies' ) )

    treeView.setHeaderHidden( True )
    treeView.hideColumn( 1 )
    treeView.hideColumn( 2 )
    treeView.hideColumn( 3 )

    treeView.show()

    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```